# How do I display black console Mac

Tags: c++, macos

I am making my first steps in C++, I would like to print the very first basic code "Hello World!" on my console, I think it is supposed to open a black window displaying it, but it is not. Instead I have a white window with this message (see picture).
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot !
[image]

Comment: Not a mac user, but it looks like the space in the path is causing an issue.

Comment: Also, here at SO it is preferred that you copy-and-paste all code and error messages into your post as text. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: As Jonny Mopp said, your terminal interprets the space in the path is the issue. Try adding quotes around your executable name.

Answer (score 3):

To make the console window appearing black, follow these steps:

- Go to the Terminal Menu and choose “Preferences” then go to "Profiles"
- Select the profile named "Pro".

Comment: That just displays the settings for Pro. The start up profile is selected via General.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps you can change the terminal colors

1. Open terminal
2. Click the **shell** option
3. Click **Edit Edit Background Color**
4. Inspector window click **profile**
5. There you can select **HomeBrew**
6. You will have black window
   [image]
   [image]

If you find useful answer like it

Answer (score 0):

As Johnny Mopp mentioned, the Space in the Project Name is a problem. Try to replace it with a underscore (1st_Project) or escape it with a \ (1st\ Project).